# Cannot read property 'document' of null - UI Bootstrap for angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I working on angular web application, and I want to use `UI Bootstrap for angular` (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)..

I downloaded the js file and added it to my index.html after angular.js and i added the `'ui.bootstrap'` to my angular module...

Now i have this error when i loading the application:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null
at m.each.contents (https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js:2:26696)
at Function.m.extend.map (https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js:2:3714)
at m.each.m.fn.(anonymous function) [as contents] (https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js:2:26777)
at fa (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:61:73)
at T (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:51:429)
at T (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:52:55)
at T (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:52:55)
at E (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:49:436)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:18:4
at l.$get.l.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:125:305)
```

On incognito it's working well.. So I tried to delete browser cache data and restart the browser and it's works in the first load and when i reloaded the page the error come back....

What can I do?
I using angular 1.3.13 and jQuery 1.11.1

Comment: There isn't enough information here to guess what the problem might be. You need to show a full example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I can't put here all my code... What information do you need? thanks